# Javascript convert date string to DateTime type(C#) format issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, combodate

I am using jquery combodate which returns me a string with date like :

```
dateString = "12-07-2006"
```

In my Razor view I have:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BirthDate)   // BirthDate is a C# variable of type DateTime
```

What I want to do in my js code is:

```
   var dateString = $('#date').combodate('getValue');   // like:   "12-07-2006"

   document.getElementById('BirthDate').value = dateString; // format is wrong
```

So far I tried multiple examples looking for similar topics, but none of them works correctly.. 
I mean in my POST function after sending a form, i have ModelState error, that it is not valid value for DateTime variable (Date = {0001-01-01 00:00:00} - that i get in post method in backend code)

Comment: what exactly you want to do, to align date format in both C# model and JS. right?

Comment: I believe you want to format `dd-mm-yyyy` into `yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s` right?

Comment: NO! 
I have string "12-07-2006" in js, and in Razor model is variable from c# of DateTime type -> I have to assign this string value and convert some way to  assign properly to this DateTime(c#) variable in javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

From the [combodate](https://vitalets.github.io/combodate/) documentation:

> All methods can be called as $(element).combodate('method', parameters).

Here is an example with [combodate](https://vitalets.github.io/combodate/):

```js
$(function(){
  var dateString = "12-07-2006"
  $('#BirthDate').combodate('setValue', dateString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vitalets/combodate/master/src/combodate.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="BirthDate" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-template="D MMM YYYY" name="date">
```

Comment: I did and it sounds to me that you want to set a string into the element with id BirthDate and combodate is not accepting it. Can you clarify your question if that is not what you are after? And before calling bullshit, maybe add at least a question mark to the text...

Comment: I want to assign value "12-07-2006"  in javascript to DateTime variable from my model

Comment: I suggest editing your question and add this sentence as a question. Maybe you can also add another tag to make it clear that this is not a question about javascript/jquery alone, but your c# framework of choice.

Comment: I described exactly what  I need a\in my post, question also is simple

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you to use momentjs because you need date time format and it's the best way. momentjs allows parsing date with the specified time zone.

```
var momentDate = moment("2014-09-15 09:00:00");
and can access the JS date object via

momentDate ().toDate();
```

please refer http://momentjs.com/ for more formats.

Comment: It;s not a solution for what i asked

Comment: try sending value like this: document.getElementById('<%=BirthDate%>').value = dateString;

Comment: You can not assign value to c# variable what you can do is to access variable value.

Comment: So if I am using some jquery tool that returns me date in string format and I want to save it to database where entity conatains C# DateTime variable, how to do that? It has to be do-able in some way

Comment: yes i am talking about date format only. you can do one thing, use hidden field with attribute runat=server and get this value server side.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just do it manually without a library to understand more of this conversion you try to make.

```
dateString = "12-07-2006";
var parts = dateString.split('-');
//please put attention to the month (parts[0]), Javascript counts months from 0:
// January - 0, February - 1, etc

// parts[0] = 12 and represents the day
// parts[1] = 7 and represents the month
// parts[2] = 2006 and represents the year
var mydate = new Date(parts[2],parts[1]-1,parts[0]);
```

And now the mydate is a Date object that you can us in your model.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving when using this and passing back the Date() obj? And where did you found the exact answer?